# Creating Certificate for Team Macs and only authorizing self to create Provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, csr

SO basically i am the owner of my Apple Id and developer account and I have a multitude of Apple Developers under me who intend to make builds all the same. When three of us register our CSRs on the Apple Developer account as registered certificates, the limit is full and it doesn't allow any more developers to access that account and gives a `missing provisioning profile` message on the team's macs which aren't registered. What I want to know is if i can create and extend certificates to my team who can use kind of my certificate or signed with my certificate, and use the same provisioning profiles everywhere. Any help in this regard is more than appreciated. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you cannot add more than 3 certificate to App Developer Platform. One options can be using the certificate on all Macs. For do this;

- Open Keychain on a Mac which has a valid developer certificate
- Select Developer Certificate with the key and export it
- Import exported Certificate to the Mac which hasn't got any developer certificate

By doing this, you can see Developer name on Xcode in Project General Tab)

P.S: Project should be latest version and has all the provision files for that certificate. If not, download provision files from Apple Developer Platform and import it to project.

Comment: This somewhat helped me. So yeah i'll mark this as complete.